# "The "highcharts" property was not passed" warning with constructorType="chart"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts, react-highcharts

I'm starting a project I want to adapt a Highchart `stockChart` react component to a regular Highchart (`chart`) component. I was adjusting it on a [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/stacked-column-sample-v2-dm9et?file=/src/Example.json) and everything was working fine.

When I moved to my local project I couldn't change `constructorType` from `stockChart` to `chart`, it compiles but when I try to run the application I get this error

## TypeError: t[n] is not a function

> t
>
> C:/src/HighchartsReact.js:30

```js
  27 | const H = props.highcharts || Highcharts;
  28 | const constructorType = props.constructorType || 'chart';
  29 | 
> 30 | if (!H) {
     | ^  31 |   console.warn('The "highcharts" property was not passed.');
  32 | 
  33 | } else if (!H[constructorType]) {
```

> (anonymous function)
>
> C:/src/HighchartsReact.js:52

```js
  49 | }
  50 | 
  51 | if (!chartRef.current) {
> 52 |   createChart();
     | ^  53 | } else {
  54 |   if (props.allowChartUpdate !== false) {
  55 |     if (!props.immutable && chartRef.current) {
```

My local project runs same dependencies as the demo, I have no clue why I'm facing this `TypeError`. According to [documentation](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react) this is the default call.

Comment: I just reproduced your demo https://codesandbox.io/s/stacked-column-sample-v2-dm9et?file=/src/Example.json on the new local project and everything works fine. For: `import Highcharts from "highcharts/highstock"` works             `constructorType="stockChart"` and `constructorType="chart"`. Do you have any additional options which could have an impact on it in your project?

Comment: I think I found the reason, on my local project I was passing some options with `Highcharts.chart = {...}` and then using `Highcharts.setOptions(Highcharts.chart)` before the component creation. Doing that for highstock works fine.

Comment: It is advised to set options in the state to avoid any issues, especially issues connected with the chart update - I am 100% sure that doing an update with state options destroys completely previous chart and render the new one - with clean DOM etc, but we don't have test it how it will work with using Highcharts.setOptions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this issue and it was as you have to specifically pass the main Highcharts object down to HighchartsReact like so:

```
import Highcharts from "highcharts";

return (
        <HighchartsReact
            highcharts={Highcharts}
            options={hiChartsOptions}
        />
    );
```